# Powerbuilder --- error when calling a Java EJB (CMIS) method which returns list of Objects

Tags: java, powerbuilder, cmis

I am developing a CMIS api java with methods for documents and folders to to communicate white Alfresco .

I'm using the Eclipse IDE, a Maven project, and the OpenCMIS dependencies.

I do the JAR import of the Java project into the Powerbuilder project and everything goes well.

When I call in Powerbuilder project the method for returning a list of documents, everything works fine, the list is saved in the Powerbuilder project.

The problem is that when I try to get a document from the list saved in the Powerbuilder project an error occurs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57EbP.png)

This error also happens with other object types

What am I going to do wrong?

Thanks for the help and sorry for my English

Comment: Did you try to upload an image? Could you please edit your question to fix it or remove it?

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. Sorry. I'm available for short contracts- could probably solve with quick screen share session but advertising here is probably in bad form. I think you either need a very detailed description; or someone to look at the code.